How to dynamically stack and unstack bar chart with chart.js
I have a barchart where i want to toggle if the bars are stacked or behind each others.

Note x-axes is stacked to be behinde each other.

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!myChart) return;

        if (barStack)
        {
            myChart.data.datasets[1].stack = "barstack";
            myChart.data.datasets[2].stack = "barstack";
            myChart.data.datasets[1].barPercentage = 1;
            myChart.data.datasets[2].barPercentage = 1;
        } else
        {
            myChart.data.datasets[1].stack = undefined;
            myChart.data.datasets[2].stack = undefined;
            myChart.data.datasets[1].barPercentage = 0.5;
            myChart.data.datasets[2].barPercentage = 1;
        }

        myChart.update();

    }, [myChart, barStack]);

options: {
    scales: {
        x: {
            stacked: true,
            },

At the first loading of the page it works as is it should with barStack = false

When i toggle to stack it, it also works

But when i then want to unstack it, it doesn't work anymore.

What could be wrong here?
Use different stacks or set stacked to false doesn't have an impact

Do you have three datasets? The images you attached seem to show only two datasets. Where is datasets[0]?

It's only a small example. datasets[0] is a line chart but it's null for this test.

You have to also work with the y scale stacked property: in the overlapping mode you have to set it false and in the
stacked mode it should be true. Here's an example of that being used:


const data = {
    labels: ['2024', '2025', '2026', '2027'],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Dataset 1',
            data: Array.from({length: 4}, () => 10 +  Math.random() * 10),
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(92, 128, 255, 0.75)',
            barPercentage: 0.5
        },
        {
            label: 'Dataset 2',
            data: Array.from({length: 4}, () => 10 + Math.random() * 10),
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(92, 128, 255, 0.5)',
            barPercentage: 1
        }
    ]
};

const config = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        scales:{
            x:{
                stacked: true
            },
            y:{
                stacked: false
            }
        },
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            }
        }
    },
};

const myChart = new Chart(document.querySelector('#myChart'), config);


document.querySelector('#stack').onclick = function(e){
    if(e.target.innerText === 'Stack'){
        e.target.innerText = 'Unstack';
        myChart.scales.y.options.stacked = true;
        myChart.data.datasets[0].barPercentage = 1;
        myChart.data.datasets[0].stack = "barstack";
        myChart.data.datasets[1].stack = "barstack";
    }
    else{
        e.target.innerText = 'Stack';
        myChart.scales.y.options.stacked = false;
        myChart.data.datasets[0].barPercentage = 0.5;
        // assigning undefined also happens to work
        delete myChart.data.datasets[0].stack;// = undefined;
        delete myChart.data.datasets[1].stack;// = undefined;
    }
    myChart.update();
}
<button id="stack">Stack</button>
<div style="min-height: 60vh">
    <canvas id="myChart">
    </canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.4.2/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>



In your original code, it doesn't seem that you had the bars stacked after you set stack on datasets, but they were
still overlapped, but the bars had equal width.
The fact that your original code doesn't work, making the bars stacked after you deleted the stack property of datasets
and the y axis doesn't have stacked set to true (it is undefined) might be considered a minor bug of
chart.js - it comes from the fact that in an update the metasets property _stacked is computed based on the previous,
un-updated value of the .stack property. This problem is easily overcome by the solution above, that is, to properly set the
y scale stacked property. Here's the erroneous code, with a console display of the _stacked and stack properties after each
update.


const data = {
    labels: ['2024', '2025', '2026', '2027'],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Dataset 1',
            data: Array.from({length: 4}, () => 10 +  Math.random() * 10),
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(92, 128, 255, 0.75)',
            barPercentage: 0.5
        },
        {
            label: 'Dataset 2',
            data: Array.from({length: 4}, () => 10 + Math.random() * 10),
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(92, 128, 255, 0.5)',
            barPercentage: 1
        }
    ]
};

const config = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        scales:{
            x:{
                stacked: true
            },
            y:{
                //stacked: false
            }
        },
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            }
        }
    },
};

const myChart = new Chart(document.querySelector('#myChart'), config);


document.querySelector('#stack').onclick = function(e){
    if(e.target.innerText === 'Stack'){
        e.target.innerText = 'Unstack';
        //myChart.scales.y.options.stacked = true;
        myChart.data.datasets[0].barPercentage = 1;
        myChart.data.datasets[0].stack = "barstack";
        myChart.data.datasets[1].stack = "barstack";
    }
    else{
        e.target.innerText = 'Stack';
        //myChart.scales.y.options.stacked = false;
        myChart.data.datasets[0].barPercentage = 0.5;
        // assigning undefined also happens to work
        delete myChart.data.datasets[0].stack;// = undefined;
        delete myChart.data.datasets[1].stack;// = undefined;
    }
    myChart.update();
    // to prove the bug described in the text
    console.log("_stacked:",myChart.getDatasetMeta(0)._stacked, "stack:", myChart.getDatasetMeta(0).stack)
}
<button id="stack">Stack</button>
<div style="height: 60vh">
    <canvas id="myChart">
    </canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.4.2/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>



